# How to zoom a mapview to annotation point by fetching latitude and longitude from dictionary on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have an application in which i am dropping multiple annotations on the map. But now i want to span my map when these annotations are dropped.This is my code for adding annotation on map.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [annotations addObjectsFromArray:appDelegate.maparray];
    NSLog(@"%@",annotations);

    if ([annotations count])
    {
        for (int i =0; i < [annotations count]; i++) 
        {
             dict  = [annotations objectAtIndex:i];
            MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
            region.center.latitude = [[dict objectForKey:@"Latitude"] floatValue];
            region.center.longitude = [[dict objectForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue];


            region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.6f;
            region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.6f;

            Title = [dict objectForKey:@"Title"];

            description = [dict objectForKey:@"DescriptionMobile"];
            NSLog(@"%@",description);
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"Image"]];
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
            image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            MyAnnotation *ann = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];

            ann.title = Title;
            ann.subtitle = description;


            [mapView addAnnotation:ann];

        }
    }

}
```

How to span my map to my annotation point so that all my annoations are visible and my map also zooms.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this code ,it worked for me

```
- (void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView *)mapView { 
    if ([mapView.annotations count] == 0) return; 

    CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord; 
    topLeftCoord.latitude = -90; 
    topLeftCoord.longitude = 180; 

    CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord; 
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90; 
    bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180; 

    for(Annotation *annotation in mapView.annotations) { 
        topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude); 
        topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude); 
        bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude); 
        bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude); 
    } 

    MKCoordinateRegion region; 
    region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5; 
    region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;      
    region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1; 

    // Add a little extra space on the sides 
    region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1; 

    // Add a little extra space on the sides 
    region = [mapView regionThatFits:region]; 
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: This works perfect in iOS 4 and 5 but gives a crash in iOS 6. Just checkout my thread on that. Good if you can help with that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699284/ios-6-map-crashes-when-calling-setregion-with-invalid-argument

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss this line:

```
ann.coordinate = region.center;
```