# iOS 6 Map crashes when calling 'setRegion' with invalid argument

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Just felt into this weird issue that is specific to iOS 6. 
I used the following codes to pin a given set of addresses in iPhone map and it was working fine with iOs 4, and 5. But crashes when running on iOS 6 with the following stack trace,

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:+0.00000000, +0.00000000 span:+177.61462012, +900.00000000>'`

The code I am using is simple as it can be,

`CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord; 
    topLeftCoord.latitude = -90; 
    topLeftCoord.longitude = 180;

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord; 
bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90; 
bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180; 

for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations) { 
    topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude); 
    topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude); 
    bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude); 
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude); 
}
region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.5;
region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.5;

region = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

`

So the issue is clearly with calculating longitudeDelta I believe as it tries to access a wrong longitude +900.000. Therefore, I changed the

above code to

`region.span.latitudeDelta= self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta /2.0002;
    region.span.longitudeDelta= self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta /2.0002;`

And the crash gets resolved but map points to a different location in the world. Hope one can shed some expert knowledge on this

Comment: your problem is with subtracting a few numbers. Put some break points in or NSLog statements and see where your final line is giving you bad numbers. Break each element into local variables and it'll be easier too.

Comment: I think the prob is regionThatFits being called with a 0 region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got it :

> " the issue is clearly with calculating longitudeDelta "

I experienced the same thing, what I do is simple :

```
-(void)myFunction
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 10;
    region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(46, 2);
    [map setRegion:region];
}
```

**It crashes after the 2nd or 3rd call of `myFunction`**, but when I use `latitudeDelta` instead of `longitudeDelta`, **it works perfectly**.

Moreover, the crash log is :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
    reason: 'Invalid Region <center:+46.00000000, +2.00000000 span:-1.99143220, +10.00000000>'
```

That makes me think the `longitudeDelta` property is quite bugged.

PS : no need to set longitudeDelta and latitudeDelta because **longitudeDelta = f(latitudeDelta)**

Answer (score 0):

Of course it crashes.

1. when there is just 1
2. When there are only n equally positioned annotations

Just consider the cases and have a backup region as the algorithm fails in that case.

e.g.

```
if(noAnnotation) setRegion: world
if(annotationCount < 2) setRegion: region for annotation1 (with a span of e.g. 0,05/0,05)
else 
    ... Do the algo
    if longitudeDelta == 0 setRegion: region for annotation1 (with a span of e.g. 0,05/0,05)
    Else setRegion: like you do now
```